# Extremas on multivariable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, hessian-matrix

if the gradient Of a function f(x,y,z) has all its partial derivatives (fx, fy) at a point p equal to zero but the partial derivative z at that point is equal to a constant i.e fz= 12.

In this case can the function have an absolute extremum at that point p? Or does the fact that not all partial derivatives equal zero make that impossible?

Comment: If $f$ is defined on a compact set $K$, then you should distinguish the case where $p$ is in the interior $K^\circ$ or the boundary $\partial{K}$ of the set. If $p \in K^\circ$ and $p$ is an extremum, then an extremum is a stationary point and therefore the gradient at that point is null (i.e. all partial derivatives at that point are equal to zero). However, this is not true if $p \in \partial{K}$.

Comment: So if say f goes from A to B, and the point p is part (belongs to) of A does that imply p is part of interior of A?

Comment: Not necessarily. In your example, we have three variables so I guess we work in $\Bbb R^3$. A point $\vec{p}$ belongs to the interior of $A \subset \Bbb R^3$ if and only if there exists $\delta > 0$ such that the open ball of radius $\delta$ and center $\vec{p}$, $B(\vec{p}, \delta) = \{\vec{x} \in \Bbb R^3 :   \left\lVert \vec{p} - \vec{x} \right\rVert \lt \delta \}$, is included in $A$. By the way, have you learnt a bit of topology of $\Bbb R^n$ ? Because you kind of need a notion to do multivariable calculus.

Comment: Yes thank you. But if we were talking about a function in Rn f: Rn-->R and since Rn is both closed and open,for a point p belonging to Rn would we have an extrama in p only if p is a critical point of f? Since Rn is closed and open it would mean that any point belonging to it would be an interior point wouldn't it?

Comment: Yep, if $A = \Bbb R^n$, $A$ is open so every point is an interior point by definition. Therefore, an extrema is a critical point as you stated, but the converse is not true.